# Script to find and convert stereo WAV's that are actually mono?

Tags: mac, library, sound-library, script

Hi I have a bunch of recordings in my library that are stereo WAV's but are actually mono. Is there a script or program for mac that would find and convert the WAV's to mono ?

Comment: Converting is trivial. Finding, not quite. Are they _really_ mono files stored in stereo format, or just stereo files with very little stereo width?

Comment: Yes they are 100% the same signal on both channels.

Answer (score 2):

A procedure that would definitely work: for each file `${f}.wav`,

- Split it up to M/S stereo, i.e. to a file `${f}_M.wav` and a file `${f}_S.wav`. For instance with

  ```
  ffmpeg -i ${f}.wav -filter_complex "[0:0]pan=1c|c0=0.5 * c0 + 0.5 * c1[mid];[0:0]pan=1c|c0 = 0.5 * c0 + -0.5 * c1[side]" -map "[mid]" ${f}_M.wav -map "[side]" ${f}_S.wav
  ```
- If `f.wav` is actually mono, then `f_S.wav` will contain silence. You can detect this by analysing the volume. This is also possible with ffmpeg

  ```
  ffmpeg -i ${f}_S.wav -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null
  ```

  but it's a bit awkward to parse the output; there's probably an easier tool for this.

  - If it is mono, overwrite `f.wav` with the equivalent mono file `f_M.wav`.
  - Else delete `f_M.wav`.
- Either way, delete `f_S.wav`.